# How can I assign/update subset of tensor shared variable in Theano?

Tags: python, numpy, theano

When compiling a function in `theano`, a shared variable(say X) can be updated by specifying `updates=[(X, new_value)]`.
Now I am trying to update only subset of a shared variable:

```
from theano import tensor as T
from theano import function
import numpy

X = T.shared(numpy.array([0,1,2,3,4]))
Y = T.vector()
f = function([Y], updates=[(X[2:4], Y)] # error occur:
                                        # 'update target must 
                                        # be a SharedVariable'
```

The codes will raise a error "update target must be a SharedVariable", I guess that means update targets can't be non-shared variables. So is there any way to compile a function to just udpate subset of shared variables?

Answer (score 32):

Use [set_subtensor](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.set_subtensor) or [inc_subtensor](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.inc_subtensor):

```
from theano import tensor as T
from theano import function, shared
import numpy

X = shared(numpy.array([0,1,2,3,4]))
Y = T.vector()
X_update = (X, T.set_subtensor(X[2:4], Y))
f = function([Y], updates=[X_update])
f([100,10])
print X.get_value() # [0 1 100 10 4]
```

There's now a page about this in the Theano FAQ: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/faq_tutorial.html

Comment: And to update non continuous values : `X_update = (X, T.set_subtensor(X[[2,4]], Y))`

Comment: [Here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/faq_tutorial.html) it says that `inc_subtensor` is preferred to `set_subtensor`

Answer (score 0):

This code should solve your problem:

```
from theano import tensor as T
from theano import function, shared
import numpy

X = shared(numpy.array([0,1,2,3,4], dtype='int'))
Y = T.lvector()
X_update = (X, X[2:4]+Y)
f = function(inputs=[Y], updates=[X_update])
f([100,10])
print X.get_value()
# output: [102 13]
```

And here is the [introduction about shared variables in the official tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html#using-shared-variables).

Please ask, if you have further questions!