# Theano gradient of subtensor

Tags: theano

I try to calculate the gradient of a scalar cost towards a weightvector manually by means of a scan operation. Yet that does not work and always returns with an error that a SubTensor is not differentiable

To make sure that the gradient can be calculated:

```
T.grad(cost, p2)
```

works perfectly. That means p2 is not disconnected from the cost. However, when I try the following:

```
 def differentiate_element(i,p2,c):
            p2element=p2[i]
            return T.grad(c,p2element)
 h2, h2_updates = theano.scan(differentiate_element,
                  sequences=T.arange(p2.shape[0]), non_sequences=[p2, cost])
```

I get the error 'theano.gradient.DisconnectedInputError: grad method was asked to compute the gradient with respect to a variable that is not part of the computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a non-differentiable operator: Subtensor{int64}.0'

This question has already been asked before: [Defining a gradient with respect to a subtensor in Theano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468482/defining-a-gradient-with-respect-to-a-subtensor-in-theano) but was not answered satisfactory. That is, assigning p2[i] to its own variable as shown does not do the trick.

Adding the option disconnected_inputs='ignore' to the inner loop will actually remove the error but no longer produce a correct output as is shown in the following short example:

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
p2=theano.shared(name="P2",value=numpy.zeros(100,dtype=theano.config.floatX),borrow=True)
x=T.scalar('x')
cost=T.sum(x*p2)

gradient=T.grad(cost,p2)

def differentiate_element(i, p2, c):
    p2element = p2[i]
    return T.grad(c, p2element, disconnected_inputs='ignore')

gradient2, grad2_updates = theano.scan(differentiate_element,
                 sequences=T.arange(p2.shape[0]),
                 non_sequences=[p2, cost])

f=theano.function([x],gradient)
g=theano.function([x],gradient2,updates=grad2_updates)

print(f(20))
print(g(20))
```

The first one, prints an array containing 20's. The second one prints an array containing 0's.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate the gradients like this and not outside the scan function? If you have a specific reason to do this please provide a more extensive example with code

Comment: It is an exmaple. This is one of the basic steps if I were to be able to compute the hessian diagonal.

Comment: Ah, okay I see, since it has huge computational cost you want to compute just the gradients you require and not the whole huge thing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to compute a gradient inside a scan function for each subtensor,  you should just compute the gradients beforehand and then iterate through the ones you need

```
p2_grad = T.grad(cost,p2)

def differentiate_element(i,p2):
            p2element=p2[i]
            return p2element

p2elements_grads, h2_updates = theano.scan(differentiate_element,
                  sequences=T.arange(p2_grad.shape[0]), non_sequences=[p2_grad])
```

***edit***

Since the main concern in calculating the Hessian diagonal is that you don't want in any case to calculate the whole Hessian and waste computational resource, what you can do to avoid the Disconnected inputs error is add `disconnected_inputs='ignore'` keyword arguement to T.grad

```
def differentiate_element(i, p2, c):
    p2element = p2[i]
    return T.grad(c, p2element, disconnected_inputs='ignore')

h2, h2_updates = theano.scan(differentiate_element,
                             sequences=T.arange(p2.shape[0]), non_sequences=[p2, cost])
```

Comment: But why does the scan of the individual elements of p2 not work ?

Comment: But even without the disconnected_inputs such a scan does not work. It complains about a subtensor not being differentiable.

Comment: Can you provide a full code example that reproduces your error? Because in my case I get no error.

Comment: Hey, wtf. I don't get an error either. Let me dig further into this. Is there any easy way to print out the exact types of what goes into something ?

Comment: You add to all the inputs a test value and then in every step of the "graph building" you can see the values of every computation. Read [this](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html#using-test-values) for more details on how to do it.

Comment: Good, I made a small test and indeed your solution no longer complains that it does not work. However ! The results are wrong. I've modified the question to reflect this new information.