# Can not update a subset of shared tensor variable after a cast

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, theano

I have the following code:

```
import theano.tensor as T

Words = theano.shared(value = U, name = 'Words')
zero_vec_tensor = T.vector()
zero_vec = np.zeros(img_w, dtype = theano.config.floatX)
set_zero = theano.function([zero_vec_tensor], updates=[(Words, T.set_subtensor(Words[0,:], zero_vec_tensor))])
```

Which is compiling fine (where `U` is a numpy array of dtype `float64`).

To prevent future type error I want to cast my shared tensor `Words` into `float32` (or `theano.config.floatX` which is equivalent as I have set `floatX` to `float32` in the config file).

I so add `Words = T.cast(Words, dtype = theano.config.floatX)` and then I get the following error:

`TypeError: ('update target must be a SharedVariable', Elemwise{Cast{float32}}.0)`.

I do not understand why. According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917849/how-can-i-assign-update-subset-of-tensor-shared-variable-in-theano), using `set_subtensor` should allow me to update a subset of the shared variable.

How can I cast my shared tensor while being able to update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to update a symbolic variable, not a shared variable.

```
U = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.float64)
Words = theano.shared(value=U, name='Words')
zero_vec_tensor = T.vector()
set_zero = theano.function([zero_vec_tensor], updates=[(Words, T.set_subtensor(Words[0, :], zero_vec_tensor))])
```

works fine because the thing you are updating, `Words` is a shared variable.

```
U = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.float64)
Words = theano.shared(value=U, name='Words')
Words = T.cast(Words, dtype = theano.config.floatX)
zero_vec_tensor = T.vector()
set_zero = theano.function([zero_vec_tensor], updates=[(Words, T.set_subtensor(Words[0, :], zero_vec_tensor))])
```

does not work because now Words is no longer a shared variable, it is a symbolic variable that, when executed, will compute a cast the values in the shared variable to `theano.config.floatX`.

The `dtype` of a shared variable is determined by the value assigned to it. So you probably just need to change the type of U:

```
U = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=theano.config.floatX)
```

Or cast it using numpy instead of symbolically:

```
U = np.dtype(theano.config.floatX).type(U)
```