# Theano set_value for casted shared variable

Tags: python, theano

In the Theano deep learning tutorial, y is a shared variable that is casted:

```
   y = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(data, dtype=theano.config.floatX))
   y = theano.tensor.cast(y, 'int32')
```

I later want to set a new value for y.

For GPU this works:

```
    y.owner.inputs[0].owner.inputs[0].set_value(np.asarray(data2, dtype=theano.config.floatX))
```

For CPU this works:

```
    y.owner.inputs[0].set_value(np.asarray(data2, dtype=theano.config.floatX))
```

Why does this require a different syntax between GPU and CPU? I would like my code to work for both cases, am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very similar problem to that described in another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627302/can-not-update-a-subset-of-shared-tensor-variable-after-a-cast/30651282#30651282).

The problem is that you are using a *symbolic* cast operation which turns the shared variable into a symbolic variable.

The solution is to cast the shared variable's value rather than the shared variable itself.

Instead of

```
y = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(data, dtype=theano.config.floatX))
y = theano.tensor.cast(y, 'int32')
```

Use

```
y = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(data, dtype='int32'))
```

Navigating the Theano computational graph via the `owner` attribute is considered bad form. If you want to alter the shared variable's value, maintain a Python reference to the shared variable and set its value directly.

So, with y being just a shared variable, and not a symbolic variable, you can now just do:

```
y.set_value(np.asarray(data2, dtype='int32'))
```

Note that the casting is happening in numpy again, instead of Theano.

Comment: The weird thing in the OP is that there is a difference between CPU and GPU - GPU seems to add an extra node, making it necessary to go back two steps instead of one. Do you have any idea where this may come from?

Comment: It's probably a `HostFromGpu` or `GpuFromHost` operation. If the graph is printed via `theano.printing.debugprint` then you'll be able to see what the extra operation is. This is part of why it's best to avoid accessing inputs/outputs/owner when not required.

Comment: so the tutorial does the casting that way since:
        # When storing data on the GPU it has to be stored as floats
        # therefore we will store the labels as ``floatX`` as well
        # (``shared_y`` does exactly that). But during our computations
        # we need them as ints (we use labels as index, and if they are
        # floats it doesn't make sense) therefore instead of returning
        # ``shared_y`` we will have to cast it to int. This little hack
        # lets ous get around this issue